# CUDA program giving garbage value

Tags: cuda

I really do not understand why the output for the below code is not a and b.

```
#include<cutil.h>
#include<iostream>
__global__ void p(unsigned char **a){


unsigned char temp[2];
temp[0] = 'a';
temp[1] = 'b';
a[0] = temp;


}

void main(){

    unsigned char **a ;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&a, sizeof(unsigned char*));
    p<<<1,1>>>(a);
    unsigned char **c;
    unsigned char b[2];
    cudaMemcpy(c, a, sizeof(unsigned char *), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(b, c[0], 2*sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for( int i=0 ; i < 2; i++){
        printf("%c\n", b[i]);
    }


    getchar();


}
```

what is wrong with my logic?

Comment: Where to begin -- this wouldn't even make sense in an ordinary program. We'll have to have a chat about pointers and local variables and arrays and strings, it seems :-)

Comment: @kerrek: is there a way to declare an array within a global function in cuda such that it exists after the function is over

Comment: The device function can (AFAIK) only allocate memory on the device. Yes, in principle you could allocate dynamic device memory in a device function and return a pointer to that memory back through an argument and then access that device memory from the host to copy the data out. (That smells of terrible design, though!) Do you really want to do that?

Comment: Because this is a poor quality question that won't ever help anybody except you. It is [too localized](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close). That is why I downvoted it and voted to close it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's leave out CUDA for now. Let's just make a function that writes data to a user-provided array. The user passes the array via a pointer:

```
void fill_me_up(int * dst)
{
  // We sure hope that `dst` points to a large enough area of memory!

  dst[0] = 28;
  dst[1] = 75;
}
```

Now, what you're doing with the local variable doesn't make sense, because you want to use the address of a local variable, which becomes invalid after you leave the function scope. The next best thing you could do is `memcpy()`, or some equivalent C++ algorithm:

```
void fill_me_up_again(int * dst)
{
  int temp[] = { 28, 75 };
  memcpy((void *)dst, (const void *)temp, sizeof(temp));
}
```

OK, now on to calling that function: We first must *provide* the target memory, and then pass a pointer:

```
int main()
{
  int my_memory[2]; // here's our memory -- automatic local storage

  fill_me_up(my_memory);     // OK, array decays to pointer-to-beginning
  fill_me_up(&my_memory[0]); // A bit more explicit

  int * your_memory = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2); // more memory, this time dynamic
  fill_me_up_again(your_memory);
  /* ... */
  free(your_memory);
}
```

(In C++ you would probably have uses `new int[2]` and `delete your_memory` instead, but by using C `malloc()` the connection to CUDA hopefully becomes clear.)

When you're moving `fill_me_up` to the CUDA device, you have to give it a device pointer rather than a host pointer, so you have to set that one up first and afterwards copy the results back out, but that's about the only change.